# Give workbook write access only to certain users

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `workbook` with rawdata. Via a `button` a user can open a UserInterface and export different subsets of the data.

Now I am looking for a way that only allows `certain users` (depending on there windows username) to do changes to the rawdata but all users can still click the button to export data.

This is as far as I got yet:

```
Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Sub AAA()
Dim UName As String * 255
Dim L As Long: L = 255
Dim Res As Long
    Res = GetUserName(UName, L)
...
End Sub
```

The code give me the Windows Username of the person who is logged into the os. 
I guess I need to do something like (let's suppose HAL is a User who shall have access to the rawdata):

```
If UName = "HAL" then
---Unlock worksheet
End If
```

But I just cannot find how to set the workbook unlock and where (and when) to set the worksheet locked. I guess setting it locked during the Open Event is a bad idea. I really would appreciate if anyone could help me here.

Comment: I think you should Lock the workbook on save (inside the BeforeSave event) and unlock it maybe in the SheetActivate event?

Comment: No need for the `function` you have there. To get the name of the user logged in just ask for it: `Debug.Print Environ("USERNAME")`. If you also care for the domain the that's `Environ("USERDOMAIN")`. The server you are logged on to is `Environ("LOGONSERVER")` with the DNS `Environ("USERDNSDOMAIN")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        sh.Protect "password"
    Next sh
    'or if only some Whorksheets need to be locked:
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawDatas").Protect "password"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    If UserIsAllowed() Then
        sh.Unprotect "password"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function UserIsAllowed() As Boolean
    UserIsAllowed = True
End Function
```

(you will need to change the UserIsAllowed function of course)